# Request for the value rather than key/id in Laravel controller

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel

I'm fetching data from database to the invoice view page using `json_encode($items);` function (particularly 'price' field by it's id) from controller, it works well. But when I insert that particular field to database only the id/key is stored rather than the actual value. Any guess how to request for the value rather than key/id in controller.

Here is the controller function:

```
public function getPurchaseItems($id) 
   {
       $items = DB::table("purchase")->where("pur_id",$id)->pluck("price","pur_id");
       return json_encode($items);
    
   }
```

Here is html code:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-1">
      <label for="in">Price</label>
      <select name="price" readonly class="form-control prc" id="price">        
      </select>
    </div>
```

Here is the script:

```
            jQuery('select[name="state"]').on('change',function(){
              
               var stateID = jQuery(this).val();
               if(stateID)
               {
                  jQuery.ajax({
                     url : 'invoice/getPurchaseItems/' +stateID,
                     type : "GET",
                     dataType : "json",
                     success:function(data)
                     {
                      
                        console.log(data);
                        jQuery('select[name="price"]').empty();
                        jQuery.each(data, function(key,value){
                           $('select[name="price"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                        });
                  
                     }
                  });
               }
               else
               {
               
                
                $('select[name="price"]').empty();
                
                  
               }
            });
```

Here is the requested data and storing to database:

```
public function insertInv(Request $request){
       $price = $request->input('price');

        $invoiceId= DB::table('invoice')->insertGetId($invo);     
        $invo_det=array('invoice_no'=>$invoiceId,'price'=>$price);

         DB::table('invoice_details')->insert($invo_det);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify Your insertInv function

Remove input() from   `$price = $request->input('price');`
OR `dd($request->all());`  and check all the values in controller are in correct format And Post the Result here

Comment: what method to use instead of input() if I remove it?

Comment: `array:22 [▼
  "_token" => "JwlkRyfXpf4pQc32QeGppVZwmWZBj9SYfBOQAA0p"
  "customer_name" => "John Doe"
  "c_email" => "john@gmail.com"
  "c_phone" => "12232"
  "billing_address" => "aaa"
  "term" => "23"
  "order_date" => "2020-07-09"
  "due_date" => "2020-07-15"
  "country" => "5"
  "state" => "44"
  "qty" => "44"
  "unit" => "44"
  "price" => "44"
  "cqty" => "23"
  "sub_total" => "232323"
  "gst" => null
  "discount" => "20"
  "net_total" => "2323232"
  "paid" => "2323"
  "due" => "2323"
  "payment_type" => "نقد"
  "invoice_msg" => "ssdfd"
]`

Comment: Nthing Just use $price = $request->price; as simple as that and after defining the varible dd($price); and check if price is printing if it is printing then everything is ok.

Comment: it's printing null

Comment: GIve me anydesk id ill fix it

Comment: I'm afraid it's not available at the moment.

Comment: first do dd($request->all()); if all the values are coming in controller then print dd($request->price); it's not possible that value is in the array and printing null when you are doing it..